Placing the - (subtract) operator in front of a positive variable returns a negative value. Why doesn't + in front of a negative var return positive?
If I have an int with a positive value, I can return a negative value by placing the - operator directly in front of it. (e.g. -myInt) But if I have an int with a negative value, using the + operator doesn't return a positive value. I'd like to understand why this is.
I am using C# and Unity, outputting to the Unity console. E.g:
myInt = 5;
Debug.Log(-myInt);

Gives an expected value of -5. But:
myInt = -5
Debug.Log(+myInt);

Gives a value of -5.
I can see I've flipped the values and operators between the examples, and so I sort of feel I should see what I am seeing; but the second example doesn't feel intuitive and I don't understand it. I expected the negative value to become a plus value.
This feels like a dumb question - thanks in advance.
ps: (Also, what's the correct way of referring to the minus in '-myInt' - am I correct in calling it an operator in this instance?)

that's just math and semantics - not really anything to do with programming (although programming respects this convention); +5 is 5, +(-5) is -5, not +5; unary addition doesn't change the sign to positive - it is a no-op

To negate use - --5 -> 5, to get absolute value, use Math.Abs: Math.Abs(-5) == 5

@ps: It is the unary minus operator.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_operation  just think of + and - as multiplication with +1 and -1. only multiplying with -1 changes the sign

What's the correct way of referring to the minus in '-myInt' - am I correct in calling it an operator in this instance - yes, although to be specific it's the unary negation operator.

I must point out that using a + prefix is not always a no-op, as the following code demonstrates: short x = 0; short y = +x;. That won't compile because +x converts the short x to an int. If it was a no-op then +x would be of type short.

-x will change the sign, so that even number of negations -(-(-(-x)))) will return x with same sign. There is no opposite to negation operation in our math and +x is just a form of explicitly saying positive value (as opposed to negative value, which you can produce by negation of positive value). But there is also another operation  to obtain absolute value Math.Abs(x) (in math |x|), which lets you to override x sign to either positive or negative (with negation -Math.Abs(x)).

In algebra -x is shorthand for 0-x and when x is positive the result is negative and vice-versa.
Similarly +x is shorthand for 0+x and when x is positive the result is positive and when x is negative the result is negative.
In programming context +x denotes the op_UnaryPlus operator.
And -x denotes the op_UnaryNegation operator.
The operator symbols and names should follow the convention of +x returning x and -x returning the negate operation for all types that support this notation.
It is important when operator overloading to keep these conventions.
See link above for the full table below describing the operators, symbols and names.



C# Operator Symbol
Metadata Name
Friendly Name




N/A
op_Implicit
To/From


N/A
op_Explicit
To/From


+ (binary)
op_Addition
Add


- (binary)
op_Subtraction
Subtract


..




--
op_Decrement
Decrement


++
op_Increment
Increment


- (unary)
op_UnaryNegation
Negate


+ (unary)
op_UnaryPlus
Plus





Placing the - (subtract) operator in front of a positive variable
returns a negative value. Why doesn't + in front of a negative var
return positive?

In your example
int myInt = -5; is the unary minus operator, not the binary subtraction operator. It negates its operand, hence changes its sign.
The unary plus operator does not change the sign. As it has no effect on its operand it can and usually will be omitted. It basically just exists for completeness.
